# Take a desired string, iterate through objects to see if it exists in a given field and append a number until a unique string is found

Tags: c#, strings, linq, generics, iterator

I wanted to in the most generic way possible write a method in C# to achieve the following.

- Take in a string, a set of objects, and a function to access the field of a given object
- Look at all of the strings from the fields of these objects to match against provided string
- If provided string is not unique in a case insensitive manner, append `_x` to the end, where `x` is an incrementing integer until a unique string is found

With that in mind, I created this.

```
private string GetUniqueStringForModel<T>(string originalString, IEnumerable<T> enumerableObjects, Func<T, string> stringFieldFunction) where T : class
{
    var uniqueString = originalString;
    var duplicateCount = 1;

    while (enumerableObjects.Select(stringFieldFunction).ToList().Any(currentString => string.Equals(currentString, uniqueString, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
    {
        uniqueString = originalString + "_" + duplicateCount++;
    }

    return uniqueString;
}
```

I would rather have not put the `ToList()` in but when working with Entity Framework it was complaining about doing the string comparison in LINQ (presumably because it couldn't compile it SQL).

Any thoughts or ideas for improvement?

Comment: I guess that `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` comparison really bothers EF. Can't you handle this on your DB column? A case insensitive collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` should work (assuming that this column is always compared this way).

Comment: I think you would get much better answers if you included more context like how this method is called, what kind of models you are working with etc. Since the `enumerableObjects` appear to be a hidden `IQueryable` I believe it should be possible to delegate more work to the sql server.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's certainly room for improvement.

1. Move that that `Select(stringFieldFunction).ToList()` out of the while loop. Iterating an `IEnumerable` might be quite expensive, and there's no need to repeat that work when you find a duplicate.
2. Select only those strings that have `originalString` as a prefix. That will reduce the amount of items you need to check against when adjusting the suffix.
3. Instead of making a list, turn those results into a (hash)set, for faster lookup.

Regarding EF complaining: apparently it doesn't support those `StringComparsion` overloads, so it'll have to fetch all rows from the database and run your `Any` predicate in memory, which may be slower as expected. Maybe an alternative approach like using `ToUpperInvariant` can be translated to SQL?

---

Applying the above changes will give you the following:

```
private string GetUniqueValue<T>(string value, IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, string> getValue)
{
    var possibleDuplicates = items
        .Select(getValue)
        .Where(val => val.StartsWith(value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        .ToHashSet();

    var result = value;
    var suffix = 1;
    while (possibleDuplicates.Contains(result))
    {
        result = value + "_" + suffix;
        suffix += 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

---

#### Addendum

As t3chb0t and ErikE already pointed out, if you want the benefits of Linq-to-SQL, then you need to use `IQueryable<T>`. Not only that, you also need to make sure that you're using the `Queryable` Linq extension methods, not the `Enumerable` variants.

The difference is that `Enumerable` methods have `Func<>` parameters, while the `Queryable` variants have `Expression<Func<>>` parameters. An `Expression` is a data structure that represents a piece of code, which makes translation to SQL possible. Because `stringFieldFunction` is a `Func`, not an `Expression<Func>`, the `Enumerable.Select` variant is used. That cannot be translated to SQL, so all data has to be loaded from the database before the `Select` (and any subsequent operation) can be performed on it.

To recap: use `IQuerable<T>`, make sure you're using `Queryable` Linq methods, and only use supported methods within your expressions.

Comment: I like solution with HashSet very much and I would like to discuss some algorithm improvements. How about trying to split string by the last `_` (before `[0-9]*`) then putting everything into `Map<string, int>` (assuming 0 when `_number` does not exist) and finally just querying the map returning just value if does not exist and `$"{value}_{map.Get(prefix) + 1}"` otherwise. What do you think?

Comment: I forgot to mention: by putting next value I mean:`Math.Max(actual, existing)`

Comment: I guess all the answers are wrong away because it looks like that the `items` is actually an `IQueryable` thus things like `StartsWith(value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)` are pointless or won't work at all. I'm pretty sure it can be solved in a much better way that compiles to sql if OP had only posted enough context.

Comment: @mpasko256: I don't really see what you mean. Maybe you could show some code?

Comment: @PieterWitvoet I would like to write code but I had trouble to load OP's original method into C# interactive neither .Net fiddle and wanted to give others opportunity. Now I see it was similar approach to Taemyr's.

Comment: @t3chb0t: if that's the case then he should also be passing in an `Expression<Func<>>` instead of a `Func<>`... it looks like the OP started with an `IQueryable` implementation and then tried to generalize it to `IEnumerable`, without realizing the implications. I'll add some notes about that.

Answer (score 5):

It will be more efficient to call `.ToList()` just once:

```
// ...
var list = enumerableObjects.Select(stringFieldFunction).ToList();
while (list.Any(currentString => string.Equals(currentString, uniqueString, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
{
    uniqueString = originalString + "_" + duplicateCount++;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
private string GetUniqueStringForModel<T>(
    string originalString,
    IQueryable<T> databaseQueryable,
    Expression<Func<T, string>> stringFieldFunction
) where T : class {
    var lowerBound = originalString.ToLowerInvariant();
    var upperBound = originalString.ToUpperInvariant() + "z";
    var candidates = new HashSet<string>(
       databaseQueryable
          .Select(stringFieldFunction)
          .Where(field => field >= lowerBound && field < upperBound)
          .ToSet()
    );

    return Enumerable
       .Range(0, int.MaxValue)
       .Select(i => originalString + (i == 0 ? "" : $"_{i}"))
       .First(candidate => !candidates.Contains(candidate));
}
```

There are a few things going on here.

First, since you are using Entity Framework and received the error you did, I believe that your `IEnumerable` is *actually* an `IQueryable`. If you want to add predicates to the query that are performed on the database server, you need to maintain the `IQueryable` as that data type and not prematurely force it to become an `IEnumerable`. This is of crucial importance to understand and I encourage you to go study the difference between these and what effects it has. The exact same code is compiled completely differently when cast to an IQueryable instead of an IEnumerable—differently in a way necessary for being able to project your C# code to SQL for doing the majority of the work in the database.

Second, your `Func` can work, but it must contain only methods and operators [that work with Entity Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities) and must be an `Expression<Func<>>`. If you want to use a method that is not supported, that can only be done by, after whatever IQueryables have filtered it so far, materializing the result set in memory using `.ToList()` and then iterate over it locally (using a regular `Func`).

My goal in the above code was to fetch the set of values that could possibly match the `originalString`. Notice that by assigning the values to variables, this leaves the queryable's `Where` clause susceptible to being read by EF, because it will be compiled as an `Expression` instead of to byte code. (That is why you need `IQueryable` instead of `IEnumerable`). The trick I used to select the appropriate range may not be a good one (I haven’t touched C# for 16 months). Study the operators and your data and pick a better one. Find the greatest value that can be added (not "z") and add that.

Third, the very limited set of results is being converted to a `Set` so that we can get O(1) lookup time. I promise you that performing a `ToList()` on an `IQueryable` (masked as an `IEnumerable`) on each new number suffix attempt is a superbly wonderful way to destroy performance. Please don't do that. Your code as written will read every single row from the underlying `IQueryable` *on every iteration of the while loop*—hopefully there are some conditions on it and this isn’t the entire table!

Fourth, you have to pay attention to the string comparison in the database and for the `HashSet`. Do you want case sensitivity or case insensitivity? Is there another kind of collation that might be needed to perform foreign language support? You need to provide the `HashSet` a `StringComparer` that will perform properly.

Fifth, why even provide a `stringFieldFunction` when the caller can just do `.Select(stringFieldFunction)` itself? This doesn't seem useful to me. Don't add unnecessary parameters. Doing it in the caller will avoid having to muck about with `Func` vs. `Expression<Func>`.

Comment: I think HashSet<string>.Contains() is case sensitive.  String.Upper() is a canonical function so is supported by any LINQ provider. - Although I am not sure if it performs the same in memory as in the db.  (In memory it will use the .Net library, in database it will use the appropriate db function)

Comment: The solution is to pass the appropriate StringComparer into the constuctor of the HashSet.

Comment: @Taemyr That’s why I said “you need to provide the HashSet a comparator they will perform properly.” Of course I meant Comparer.

Answer (score 2):

ToUpper translates into SQL allowing you to avoid the StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase.

In addition the IsNumeric function allows you to guard so that you can use parse the string to get the counter directly (In LinqtoEntities with a MSSQL backend .Cast() performs this function).

Finally when operating with queryables you need to use an Expression rather than a Func

This allows the following;

```
private string GetUniqueStringForModel<T>(
  string originalString, 
  IQueryable<T> enumerableObjects, 
  Expression<Func<T, string>> stringFieldFunction
) where T : class
{
IQueryable<String> enumerableStrings=Queryable.Select<T,string> 
(enumerableObjects,stringFieldFunction);

if(!enumerableObjects.Select(stringFieldFunction).Any(
x=>x.ToUpper()==originalString.ToUpper()))
return originalString;

originalString=originalString+"_";
var length=originalString.Length;

if(!enumerableStrings.Any(
x=>x.ToUpper().StartsWith(originalString.ToUpper())&&
System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.IsNumeric(
x.Substring(length)) == 1))
return originalString+"1";

var highest=
  enumerableStrings
  .Where(x=>(x.ToUpper().StartsWith(originalString.ToUpper())) &&
    System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.IsNumeric(
    x.Substring(length)) == 1)
  .Select(x=>x.Substring(length))
  .Cast<int>()
  .Max()+1;
return originalString+highest;
}
```

Not quite the same as your code, if you have "Foo", "Foo_1" and "Foo_5" your code will return "Foo_2" while the above should return "Foo_6", but it's only 3 db calls, and each only return a single row.

Comment: You can use LinqToEntities in LinqPad if you load the correct library... :)